# Get the category fields even if there is no post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have one small problem, i am showing the custom fields of category on category page. its showing fine. but its not showing if there is no post in that category.

i don't know where to use the 'hide_empty' => 0 in my code.

here is the code which i used to show the fields of category.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');

if( !empty($terms) ) {

$term = array_pop($terms);
$expert_photo = get_field('expert_photo',$term);
$expert_name = get_field('expert_name',$term);
$expert_title = get_field('expert_title',$term);
$expert_description = get_field('expert_description',$term);
$expert_introduction = get_field('expert_introduction',$term);
```

Comment: You want to display all the terms? Regardless of current post? Use [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_get_object_terms()`. The function  will get all the terms available in taxonomies based on the arguments supplied.

```
wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category', array( 'fields' => 'slug' ) );
```

For more info can be found in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

Comment: And how it will display the terms that is not in post ?